# how to print the JDBC request and response headers in Beanshell PostProcessor

Tags: javascript, java, performance, groovy, jmeter

I am using Beanshell postprocessor to generate the result
I am able to print the http-sampler request and response and so on..and also printing JDBC response But
I am not able to print the JDBC request and response headers, Can you please someone help on this
For example http sampler code :
[image]

Can we print the same way for JDBC request and response headers

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot print JDBC request headers because there is no such a concept in the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), request headers are specific to [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP), [JMS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html) and [SMTP](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)
2. With regards to response headers you can get basic connection information using the following code:

   ```
   log.info(prev.getResponseHeaders())
   ```

   [image]

   which should be the same info you can observe in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

   [image]
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) on next available opportunity. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.